# Умножение матриц

Tags: java, матрицы

Нужно умножить две матрицы и получить результат в консоли.

```
public class MatrixCreator {

    private int[][] matrix;
    private int n;
    private int m;

    public MatrixCreator(int n, int m) {
        this.n = n;
        this.m = m;
        matrixRandomFill(n, m);
    }

    public void matrixRandomFill(int n, int m) {
        matrix = new int[n][m];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("\nMatrix: " + matrix.length + "x" + matrix[0].length + "\n");
        for (int[] row : matrix) {
            for (int value : row) {
                sb.append(value + " ");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Далее метод main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MatrixCreator matrix = new MatrixCreator(4, 4);
    System.out.println(matrix);
    MatrixCreator matrix2 = new MatrixCreator(4, 4);
    System.out.println(matrix2);

}
```

Получается у меня есть 2 матрицы, мысль есть такая что нужен метод:

```
public void matrixMultiply(тут на вход идёт 2 матрицы) {
    тело метода умножения
}
```

Правильно ли я мыслю? 
Когда пробовал реализовать этот метод, то на вход нельзя принять 2 матрицы, а если принимать просто `matrix`, то не понимаю как потом поэлементно умножить, т.е. я могу взять элемент одной матрицы, а второй нет.

Вопрос: как реализовать теперь метод который будет принимать 2 матрицы и умножать их?

Comment: `когда пробовал реализовать этот метод, то на вход нельзя принять 2 матрицы` можете показать в вопросе как именно вы пробовали это сделать и что не так было с тем методом

Comment: public void matrixMultiply(int[][] matrix, int[][] matrix2){
     тело метода   
    }
а вот как их умножать внутри это вопрос

Comment: так надо передавать в метод тип MatrixCreator, а не int[][]. Вот и ругается. Вы ведь создаете класс, в котором содержится матрица... должно быть `matrixMultiply(MatrixCreator matrix, MatrixCreator matrix2){ }`  в котором будет обращение к матрицам через `matrix.matrix` и `matrix2.matrix`  соответственно.......... либо должен быть метод в классе `getMatrix` который будет возвращать матрицу int[][]. Тогда метод сможет принимать на вход их самых

Comment: Спасибо Вам, задача решена!